# Struts2 Iteration of ArrayList with JavaBean

Tags: struts2, arraylist, iteration

This Question may be asked in several threads...but could not fine the correct answer

a Java Bean

```
package com.example;

public class Document {
  private String name;
  public String getName() {
     return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  } 
}
```

An ArrayList creation of JavaBean as displayed below

```
    package com.example;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class classdocs {

     public ArrayList getData() {
       ArrayList docsmx = new ArrayList();
       Document d1 = new Document();
       d1.setName("user.doc");
       Document d2 = new Document();
       d2.setName("office.doc");
       Document d3 = new Document();
       d3.setName("transactions.doc");
       docsmx.add(d1);
       docsmx.add(d2);
       docsmx.add(d3);
       return docsmx;
      }
   }
```

an Action Class

package com.example;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class FetchAction extends ActionSupport {
        private String username;
        private String message;
        private ArrayList docsmx = new ArrayList();

        public ArrayList getDocuments() {
            return docsmx;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String execute() {
            classdocs  cx = new classdocs();

            if( username != null) {         
                docsmx = cx.getData();  
                return "success";
            } else {
                message="Unable to fetch";
                return "failure";
            }
        }
    }
```

Jsp  with Struts2 Iterator Tag

```
Documents uploaded by the user are:</br>
<s:iterator value="docsmx">     
<s:property value="name" /></br>
</s:iterator>
```

Question Why the ArrayList of Bucket containing JavaBean not displayed when Iterated ...

Am I doing some thing wrong ???

with regards
karthik

Answer (score 1):

Depending your version, you should either provide a getter for `docsmx` (preferred, pre-S2.1.mumble), or make `docsmx` public (not as preferred, S2.1+).

Or, based on your code, use the correct getter:

```
<s:iterator value="documents">     
  <s:property value="name" /></br>
</s:iterator>
```

A couple of notes: `documents` should likely be declared a `List`, not `ArrayList`, although in this case it almost certainly doesn't matter. It's a good habit to get in to, though, coding to an interface when the implementation doesn't matter.

I'd also consider tightening up the code a little bit:

```
public String execute() {
    if (username == null) {
        message = "Unable to fetch";
        return "failure";
    }

    docsmx = cs.getData();            
    return "success";
}
```

This allows a more natural reading, makes it more clear what the two states are (success and failure), keeps them very distinct, and slightly shorter.